# Google Directions API query limit

Tags: android

The url http://code.google.com/intl/lv/apis/maps/documentation/directions/ includes the following :-

> > >
> >     Usage Limits
> >     Use of the Google Directions API is subject to a query limit of 2,500 directions requests per day.

<<<

Does this apply to a per handset basis (ie each handset is allowed 2,500 directions requests per day) or per app as a whole (ie only 2,500 directions requests per day allowed for that app, regardless of the number of handsets invloved). I know the Premium Service allows 100,000 request, but it is a bit expensive.

Thanks very much in advance

Paul

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the Google Directions API does not require a Google Maps api key then it probably goes by the requestor's IP address, so each individual user has 2500 requests per day.

Comment: Thanks very much for the reply. However, it has been suggested that  requests from a mobile are directed to a Mobile company's server, and it is this which makes the actual request to the Google Directions web service. Therefore the limit applies to this server’s IP address as opposed to the mobile’s IP address, and means that all users whose request ends up on a particular server have to share this 2500 request limit. Any thoughts on this ?? Thanks very much

Comment: Just to clarify, some (maybe all, I haven't exhaustively checked) of the Google Maps API web services (as opposed to Javascript) do not require an API key at this point in time: 2013-09-13.  Their T&C's are a bit cloudy...it says here that only some APIs have usage limits https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#usage_apis.  Also, re: the IP address issue, it depends on network config as to whether you have a unique IP as far as the outside world is concerned. Just did a test on whatismyip.com, on wifi I have same IP as wife's phone, both on 3g same network we have different IPs. YMMV obviously.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that when using Google Maps, that you are required to use a 'Maps API key'.  I imagine the limit is based on that.

Comment: but the Google Directions API doesn't require any key!!

Comment: so have you tried this? Is the limit as @Robby Pond says, i.e. 2500 requests per mobile user?  Thank you!