# understanding Google Directions API daily queries limitation

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm planning to use Google Directions API for bulding routes of a taxi-drive in an Android application for taxi drivers. I don't clearly understand the limit of 2500 route queries per day. Which basis is the number of requests is counted by? 2500 queries per IP-address of a client? Or somehow else? I have noticed [Google Directions API query-limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5302780/google-directions-api-query-limit) here. There was a proposal there about the limitation per mobile company server but no comments, no answers to that.

Comment: According to me that limitation will be on basis of your API Key and without API key you can not call direction API.

Comment: Directions API does not require any API key! Please note, I use this, the latest: [https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/)

Comment: @DmitriNovikov it DOES require api key. Check the sample request in that link: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Toronto&destination=Montreal&key=API_KEY

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is per IP address. However, be aware that many mobile services will have devices share IP addresses. Therefore you may want to implement a fall-back web application. Also, make sure you are within there terms of service for your application, and investigate Google Maps API for Business for higher quotas.

Comment: Is this still true today?